# getStartDateFromUri (Udacity Sunshine app - lesson 4 ContentProvider)

Tags: java, android

**From Udacity Developing Android Apps Course
(Sunshine App)**

**Lesson 4 ContentProvider**

[from this link at line 160](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/4.12_query/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/data/WeatherContract.java#L158)

```
public static long getStartDateFromUri(Uri uri) {
                        String dateString = uri.getQueryParameter(COLUMN_DATE);
                        if (null != dateString && dateString.length() > 0)
                            return Long.parseLong(dateString);
                        else
                            return 0;
                        }
```

**where COLUMN_DATE = "date"**

the **getStartDateFromUri** function will always return 0...

can you please tell me when it will not return 0 ?
if possible give me an uri to try it

i tried

```
content://com.example.android.sunshine.app/weather/
content://com.example.android.sunshine.app/weather/94074
content://com.example.android.sunshine.app/weather/94074/20140612
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

According to the second video entitled "Create Content Provider" of the Content Provider lesson, the date parameter is in the unix timestamp form.
Try with

```
content://com.example.android.sunshine.app/weather/94074/1464566400
```